# Use car speaker via bluetooth over "faked" phone call from iOS apps

Tags: ios, bluetooth, voice

I noticed that iOS Google Maps app and Skype app both play out sound from my car's speaker via bluetooth.

My car's manufacturer only allows my phone to use the car speaker for phone calls (unless you pay more money for "enhanced bluetooth"), so both apps play the trick of "faked" phone calls, i.e. I saw from my car's dashboard that I'm calling myself, when Google Maps provides voice turn-to-turn navigation.

Haven't done iOS programming much, I'm wondering if there is any code example to achieve this purpose. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Has this mystery of yours been solved? If so, do you mind sharing? Thanks